# Is it possible to make a drag-and-drop batch script that copies files?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to make a batch script with [Hackoo's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080770/hackoo) answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44577446/open-file-by-dragging-and-dropping-it-onto-batch-file?rq=1) question to repurpose it for copying files instead of opening them. Is this something that can be done using a similar structure? Here is my revision of the script:

```
@echo off
Title Drag and drop a font to install.
Mode con cols=60 lines=3
IF [%1] EQU [] Goto:Error
CD /D "%~1">nul 2>&1 && Goto:Explorer_Folder || Goto :OpenFile
Exit /b

:OpenFile <File>
COPY "Drag and drop your font here..." "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Adobe\Fonts" "%~1"
Exit /b

:Explorer_Folder <Folder>
Explorer "%~1"
Exit /b

:Error
Color 0C & echo(
ECHO    You must drag and drop a font into this tool!
Timeout /T 5 /NoBreak >nul
Exit /b
```

Comment: Is it possible?  Possibly.  But it would probably be better to use PowerShell or VBScipt instead of a batch file.  Either way, the question is off topic.\

Comment: So are you essentially saying you want to drag a file or multiple files onto a batch file and the batch file will copy them to the Adobe Fonts folder?

Comment: That is correct @Squashman.

Comment: So the basic syntax for the copy command is `COPY SOURCE DESTINATION`. The source is the argument passed to the batch file which is `%1`.  Your destination is `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Adobe\Fonts`.